# React Native webview bearer code

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

I have a website that uses Oauth2 to log the user into the user portal. 
I created a React Native application that opens a webview on the sign in page of the website.

How do I catch the bearer code that are coming from Oauth2 after the users press the sign in button and before the portal opens.

How would I catch that bearer code to use it in further API requests.

I have been struggling a few days on this now.

Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using Expo?

Comment: Nope, I am using the native way of React Native.